# My app works on API 19, but doesn't on higher API levels

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

I am a new android developer, and i am having some problems when running my app on `API` 22. It works perfectly fine on my phone and my father's (both `API` 19), but when i run it on my mother's (`API` 22), it just crashes.  I don't know why it's happening, and don't know how to fix it.

//Content main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnface"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/btnfb"
        android:autoLink="all"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnsite"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick=""
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/btnsite"
        android:autoLink="all"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnwhats"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnwhats"
        android:autoLink="all"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

//Activity main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"        
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/title"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

//Main Activity

```
package rafael.couto.appseutimenarede;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnface;
private Button btnsite;
private Button btnwhats;
private WebView site;
private WebView face;

private static final String TAG = "lifecycle";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    btnface = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnface);
    btnsite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsite);
    btnwhats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnwhats);

    btnface.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse("fb://page/801562049877312/")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //open play link in browser
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse("http://www.facebook.com/Seu-Time-na-Rede-801562049877312/")));
            }
        }//fecha onClick
    });//fecha listener

    btnsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://seutimenarede.wix.com/fotografias");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnwhats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto: 5191598071");
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
            i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "Entrou no onCreate");
}//fecha onCreate
}//fecha main
```

LogCat

```
12-07 23:45:20.996 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
12-07 23:45:21.047 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/chromium: [ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(258)] Failed to init browser shader disk cache.
12-07 23:45:21.059 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
12-07 23:45:21.333 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 44632364 byte allocation with 8388512 free bytes and 40MB until OOM"
12-07 23:45:21.390 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 44632364 byte allocation with 8388512 free bytes and 40MB until OOM"
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime: Process: rafael.couto.appseutimenarede, PID: 2794
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 44632364 byte allocation with 8388512 free bytes and 40MB until OOM
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2477)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2384)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3742)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:637)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:64)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:60)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:926)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at rafael.couto.appseutimenarede.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
12-07 23:45:21.394 2794-2794/rafael.couto.appseutimenarede E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: check if in your manifest is something like this
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: You have a 44MB uncompressed image you are trying to load into memory. Can you post the dimensions and what directory your image is stored in?

Comment: ianhanniballake, I got lighter icons and now it works. Thank you :)